# linq and 2d integer arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

How make this with LINQ?

```
public uint[,] pole;
public uint selColor;

for (int y = 0; y < cellsamount; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < cellsamount; x++)
    {
        if (pole[x, y] == selColor)
            pole[x, y] = 0;
    }
}
```

Is this possible or better to leave it as is?

Comment: "LINQ rule #1": Unless you are able to come with LINQ query yourself in 3 minutes, it is not worth using it. :)

Comment: LINQ isn't very good for modifying sequences. Unless you want to create a new array you should leave this as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you'd do it (but I don't recommend it, it's not very sexy). Better keep your current solution.

```
pole = pole.Select(i =>
    i.Select(j => j == selectColor ? 0 : j).ToArray()
).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var selectedIndices =
  from x in Enumerable.Range(0, cellsamount)
  from y in Enumerable.Range(0, cellsamount)
  where pole[x, y] == selColor
  select new { x, y };

foreach (var index in selectedIndices.ToArray())
  pole[index.x, index.y] = 0;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it takes up more space than my version.

Comment: @user2160453: What do you mean by "more space"?

Comment: More characters of the code.